# Integrating differential with time-dependent arguments

Tags: python, math, numpy, scipy, time-series

I've been trying to get an actual (start data value + Integral(0-t) result) value from a differential equation. The arguments of the equation are all time dependent. Below is an example of such an equation:

```
dx/dt = a + sin(b) + ln(c) + 5*x
```

I've tried integrating the equation with `scipy.integrate.ode` using the following code:

```
startValue = 3.5
timeEnd = 4
variables = { 'a': 3.24, 
              'b': 4.56, 
              'c': 2.1, 
              'x': 3.77 }
def computeValue(startValue, timeEnd, variables):

    r = integrate.ode(computeDifferential).set_integrator('vode', method='bdf')
    r.set_initial_value(startValue)
    r.set_f_params(variables)

    tStart = 0.0
    tStep = 1
    tFinal = timeEnd 
    numSteps = int(numpy.floor((tFinal - tStart)/tStep)) + 1
    t = numpy.zeros((numSteps, ))

    k = 1
    results = numpy.empty((numSteps, ))
    while r.successful() and k < numSteps:
        r.integrate(r.t + tStep)
        t[k] = r.t
        results[k] = r.y[0]
        k += 1

    return results

def computeDifferential(t, x, args):
    return args['a'] + sin(args['b']) + ln(args['c']) + 5*x
```

Where `startValue` is the start value of the time series data, `timeEnd` is the row of data I want to integrate to (if data is gathered in time steps of 1 then time end of 5 will be the 5th row of data), `variables` holds the fifth row of data including the `x` variable.

So because the variable `t` is not used in the computation of the this particular example of equation, I am struggling getting some sensible results. I think my whole maths might be wrong.

What I am trying to achieve is to integrate from 0 to t (where t is the row offset assuming timestep 1 for my data) dx/dt

My issue is that I can't understand whether I should be changing all my variables according to time and assume that for integrating from 0 to 5 I will need 0-5 data rows from my data.

I realise that there might be many unclear things about this question, but I will try to clear things up when questions arise.

Edit 1: So the differential equation could be different, so the solution I am looking for should be generic, thus the function computeDifferential().

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of what you pass in, ie `args['a'] = ?what?`

Comment: This is array containing a data row from the data set and every variable can be accessed by name

Answer (score 0):

If performance is not of utmost importance you can just calculate the integral using an implementation of Euler forward.

```
steps = 10;
tMin = 0;
tMax = 5;
dt = (tMax-tMin)/steps
timeValues = [dt*i for i in range(steps)]
aValues = [aFunc(t) for t in timeValues]
bValues = [bFunc(t) for t in timeValues]
cValues = [cFunc(t) for t in timeValues]
xValues = [xFunc(t) for t in timeValues]

sinValues = [math.sin(b) for b in bValues]
lnValues = [math.log(c) for c in cValues]
xMultiValues = [5*x for x in xValues]

aIntegral = sum([aVal*dt for aVal in aValues])
sinIntegral = sum([bVal*dt for bVal in sinValues])
lnIntegral = sum([cVal*dt for cVal in lnValues])
xIntegral = sum([xVal*dt for xVal in xMultiValues])

totIntegral = aIntegral + sinIntegral + lnIntegral + xIntegral
```

Of course there are better ways to numerically integrate, such as using Runge-Kutta 4 or another method of order `>1`. I'm also fairly certain that there are more efficient ways to create the arrays of values using numpy.

Comment: Unfortunately I need a generic solution for the equation, also this will be running on relatively big data sets so execution time is not that irrelevant. Thank you though